# Prediction using ID3 algorithm,Accord.Net framework

Tags: c#, machine-learning, classification, prediction, id3

I am using following code to find the expected sales for a given item when changing its price,discount, and advertisement on item. This is implemented using ID3 algorithm using Accord.Net libraries.

```
namespace PnredictionSales
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable data = new DataTable("Sales prediction Example");

        data.Columns.Add("RowKey");
        data.Columns.Add("Brand");
        data.Columns.Add("PriceRange");
        data.Columns.Add("Discount");
        data.Columns.Add("Advertisement");
        data.Columns.Add("ExpSales");

        //  data.Columns.Add("Wind");
        //  data.Columns.Add("PlayTennis");

        data.Rows.Add("D1", "Highland", "R1", "yes", "No", "B");
        data.Rows.Add("D2", "Highland", "R1", "yes", "yes", "C");
        data.Rows.Add("D3", "Anchor", "R1", "yes", "No", "B");
        data.Rows.Add("D4", "Flora", "R2", "yes", "No", "B");
        data.Rows.Add("D5", "Flora", "R3", "No", "No", "A");
        data.Rows.Add("D6", "Flora", "R3", "No", "yes", "A");
        data.Rows.Add("D7", "Anchor", "R3", "No", "yes", "A");
        data.Rows.Add("D8", "Highland", "R2", "yes", "No", "B");
        data.Rows.Add("D9", "Highland", "R3", "No", "No", "A");
        data.Rows.Add("D10", "Flora", "R2", "No", "No", "B");
        data.Rows.Add("D11", "Highland", "R2", "No", "yes", "B");
        data.Rows.Add("D12", "Anchor", "R2", "yes", "yes", "A");
        data.Rows.Add("D13", "Anchor", "R1", "No", "No", "B");
        data.Rows.Add("D14", "Flora", "R2", "yes", "yes", "A");

        Codification codebook = new Codification(data);

        DecisionVariable[] attributes =
        {
            new DecisionVariable("Brand", 3),  new DecisionVariable("PriceRange",3),
            new DecisionVariable("Discount",2),new DecisionVariable("Advertisement",2) 
        };

        int classCount=3; // 2 possible output values for playing tennis: yes or no

        DecisionTree tree = new DecisionTree(attributes, classCount);

        // Create a new instance of the ID3 algorithm
        ID3Learning id3learning = new ID3Learning(tree);

        // Translate our training data into integer symbols using our codebook:
        DataTable symbols = codebook.Apply(data);
        int[][] inputs = symbols.ToIntArray("Brand", "PriceRange","Discount","Advertisement");
        int[] outputs = symbols.ToIntArray("ExpSales").GetColumn(0);

        // Learn the training instances!

        id3learning.Run(inputs, outputs);
        int[] query = codebook.Translate("Flora","R1","yes","No");

        int output = tree.Compute(query.ToDouble());

        string answer = codebook.Translate("ExpSales", output); // answer will be "No".
        Label1.Text = answer;
    }
}
```

and my question is:

When I put any string values to `int[] query = codebook.Translate("fff","eee","ffg","qqq");` it gives me an output. I want to what is the reason for this? Is my approach wrong?
Also I want to know what is the minimum requirement of organizing data in datatable in order to get an accurate result.

Answer (score 2):

I tried running your code - but I got an exception rather than any output. Looking at it I think the problem is that when you create the Codification you don't specify which columns to include, so it includes the RowKey column and then nothing lines up. Instead create the Codification with :

```
Codification codebook = new Codification(data, "Brand", "PriceRange", "Discount", "Advertisement", "ExpSales");
```

and it then seems to work.

When I try your example of `int[] query = codebook.Translate("fff","eee","ffg","qqq");` again I just get an exception (because those values weren't present) - so I think you must have an exception handler hiding these problems from you.

In terms of the minimum data to get accurate results - it really depends how complex the data is and how much noise it contains. You need to train the model against one set of data and then test its accuracy against a completely different set of data in order to measure if its working.